# Github PR shows file changes that are already there in the branch

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

1. There exist a develop branch and feature1 branch that were in sync
2. Then, I committed a few changes in the develop branch, by mistake (3 commits to be precise)
3. I then switched to feature1 branch and cherry picked the few changes (3 commits).
4. Then i made a few changes in the feature1 branch ( 1 new commit).
5. I Created a PR for merging feature1 into develop (feature1 ===>> develop).

The `Files Changed` section of the pr now shows changes that i had cherry picked ( the changes in the 3 commits).
**But develop already has those changes**.
I evidently cherry picked the changes from develop itslef. Then why does a pr show chages that are already present in the branch that i cherry picked from.

[image]

Possible Reason

Is it because **[cherry pick creates a new commit hash](https://opensource.com/article/21/3/git-cherry-pick#:%7E:text=Please%20note%20that%20cherry%2Dpicking%20commits%20will%20create%20a%20fresh%20commit%20with%20a%20new%20hash)**.
Github compares the branches by commit hash and since it finds a new hash
It just shows the changes done in the new hash

An answer on Microsoft develop community also shows, [How github compares two branches?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pr-changelogs-shows-non-existing-files-to-be-delet/887426)

Comment: Not really related to hashes. You see that because PRs changes in github and such are calculated with `...` (triple dot), not `..` (double dot) (like `git diff main...feature`). It is to be expected. When doing a `git cherry-pick` there is _no_ metadata for git to know that the _original_ commits are already part of the history of the target branch.

Comment: Cherry pick doesn't only create a new hash, it creates a completely new commit. Also, what do you mean by "in sync"? Did both branches point to the same commit?

Comment: When we say a new hash, it means a new commit. As commit is identified by it's hash, so a new hash = new commit. BTW, i will quote myself again from above "cherry pick creates a new commit hash". And by inSync i meant that feature was merged to develop at that time.

Comment: Is it possible that your 3 accidental commits are on your **local** development branch, but (thankfully) not on the remote branch?

Comment: No, i can confirm that all the commits were on remote. The 3 accidental and the 1 after cherry pick all.

Comment: @JalajYadav_Avesta Okay, thanks :) Then I'm not sure what's going on if not only 1 new commit, but also any resulting file changes are displayed. The only explanation I can think of would be git finding a different place to insert those changes in the file. Causing them to end up *twice* in the target file, but at different locations/lines. It's something that can happen, especially when cherry-picking, if the file has a lot of similar lines that can cause diff context (mis)matching.